# Sign In change to Sign out when is logged in

Tags: ios, ruby, key-value-observing, rubymotion

Sorry it abit long,hope you guys understand

I have a list of items in my tableView which it is JASidePanelController
Eg:

```
@menu =  { 'menu' => ['Item1','Sign In'] }
```

This list will be in every of my cell.
When I perform Sign In action successfully, how do I automatically update the Sign In into Sign out?

There is

- main_controller
- menu_controller(JASidePanel)

when I clicked sign in, it will go to

- sign_in_controller

When successfully, i just able to do
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
but the menu_controller is not updated. If I close the app and reopen,the update only will reflect.

I'm using **App::Persistence['session']** to determine whether a user is logged in or not. 
I research alot and maybe KVO is the solution?

Anyone had done this before and point me to the right direction?
Example app: **Scribd**

Answer (score 0):

Call `setNeedsLayout` on the menu's view if you've managed to set it but it's just not updating, though I'm unsure of why your setup would require hackery like this. I'll update my answer if some source code is provided and I was wrong.

Comment: is setNeedsLayout is JASidePanelController provided? I'm not really understand what you re pointing to...

Comment: setNeedsLayout is a method on of UIView and all subclasses, see the docs: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsLayout